HP ProLiant DL380 G8 server memory errors
I have a HP ProLiant DL380p G8 server that is having issues with its RAM. It restarts on its own, and one of the RAM module indicator lights turns on.
After replacing the RAM, it ran for two days,  then restarted again with another RAM error.
Could it be that multiple RAM modules are faulty, or is there another underlying issue?
Also, in the past month, three hard drives failed within a few days of each other, and I had to replace them. I also replaced the cache battery. Could the RAM error be related to the cache battery?

What does the IML show?

Could the RAM error be related to the cache battery? Unless your root cause is bad grounding or other electrical problems, this is very unlikely

@mfinni Assuming that there are electrical problems, can you explain the relationship between the cache battery and the RAMs?
And which one is the problem and should be replaced?
Does a defective cache battery cause the destruction of RAMs, or will the problem of RAMs be solved by replacing a new cache battery?!

There is NO connection between the RAID card cache battery and the motherboard RAM, which was my point. The only way they could have related problems would be if you had bad electrical source problems or some other physical/environment problem.

That server's old, it's probably worth simply replacing it.
